# populating methods into typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript API which takes in a string filtering object

```
@InputType()
export class StringFilter {
  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  value?: string;
  @Field(() => [String], { nullable: true })
  values?: string[];

  @Field(() => ComparisonType)
  operation: ComparisonType = ComparisonType.EQUALS;

  get sql(): string {
    return 'some sql';
  }

  constructor(filter: StringFilter) {
    Object.assign(this, filter);
  }
}
```

And as you can see I have declared a function `sql` as I think it would be pretty neat to be able to run `filter.sql` instead of creating a bunch of helper functions outside the scope of this specific filter.

But here is the problem:
The filter is being used as a DTO, meaning that I am not getting the `sql` function(it is just undefined).
I can only assume that apollo or nest is just casting an `any` object to `StringFilter`, giving me the fields but not the methods.

I can do `new StringFilter(filter).sql`, but that seems pretty chatty and doesn't look very nice.
So are there any good options of populating methods on a DTO class?